# Error with caret package - classification v regression

Tags: r, r-caret

I am an actuarial student preparing for an upcoming predictive analytics exam in December. Part of an exercise is to build a model using boosting with `caret` and `xgbTree`. See the code below, the caravan dataset is from the `ISLR` package:

```
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1000)
data.Caravan <- read.csv(file = "Caravan.csv")


data.Caravan$Purchase <- factor(data.Caravan$Purchase)
levels(data.Caravan$Purchase) <- c("No", "Yes")


data.Caravan.train <- data.Caravan[1:1000, ]
data.Caravan.test <- data.Caravan[1001:nrow(data.Caravan), ]
grid <- expand.grid(max_depth = c(1:7),
                    nrounds = 500,
                    eta =  c(.01, .05, .01),
                    colsample_bytree = c(.5, .8),
                    gamma = 0,
                    min_child_weight = 1,
                    subsample = .6)

control <- trainControl(method = "cv", 
                        number = 4,
                        classProbs = TRUE,
                        sampling = c("up", "down"))
              
caravan.boost <- train(formula = Purchase ~ .,
                       data =  data.Caravan.train, 
                       method = "xgbTree", 
                       metric = "Accuracy",
                       trControl = control, 
                       tuneGrid = grid)
```

The definitions in `expand.grid` and `trainControl` were specified by the problem, but I keep getting an error:

> Error: sampling methods are only implemented for classification problems

If I remove the sampling method from `trainControl`, I get a new error that states "Metric Accuracy not applicable for regression models". If I remove the Accuracy metric, I get an error stating

> cannnot compute class probabilities for regression" and "Error in names(res$trainingData) %in% as.character(form[[2]]) : argument "form" is missing, with no default"

Ultimately the problem is that caret is defining the problem as regression, not classification, even though the target variable is set as a factor variable and `classProbs` is set to TRUE. Can someone explain how to tell caret to run classification and not regression?

Comment: Could you add the outcome from `dput(head(data.Caravan, 20))` to your question? This will give us the first 20 records of your source data. That way we can run your code with your data. For more info read this post on [reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @phiver thanks for the reply. The dataset has 86 fields. That may be too much to paste in here. The caravan dataset is available in the ISLR package.

Comment: @missuse thanks for the comment. I'm not sure what you meant by not using the formula interface, so I tried a couple of iterations of different things and found something that worked. The only thing I changed was "formula = Purchase~."  to "Purchase~." and it worked. I have no idea why though. How did you know to do that?

Answer (score 1):

`caret::train` does not have a `formula` argument, but rather a `form` argument in which you specify  the formula. So for instance this works:

```
caravan.boost <- train(form = Purchase ~ .,
                       data =  data.Caravan.train, 
                       method = "xgbTree", 
                       metric = "Accuracy",
                       trControl = control, 
                       tuneGrid = grid)

#output:
eXtreme Gradient Boosting 

1000 samples
  85 predictor
   2 classes: 'No', 'Yes' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (4 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 751, 749, 750, 750 
Addtional sampling using up-sampling

Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  eta   max_depth  colsample_bytree  Accuracy   Kappa     
  0.01  1          0.5               0.7020495  0.10170007
  0.01  1          0.8               0.7100335  0.09732773
  0.01  2          0.5               0.7730581  0.12361444
  0.01  2          0.8               0.7690620  0.11293561
  0.01  3          0.5               0.8330506  0.14461709
  0.01  3          0.8               0.8290146  0.06908344
  0.01  4          0.5               0.8659949  0.07396586
  0.01  4          0.8               0.8749790  0.07451637
  0.01  5          0.5               0.8949792  0.07599005
  0.01  5          0.8               0.8949792  0.07525191
  0.01  6          0.5               0.9079873  0.09766492
  0.01  6          0.8               0.9099793  0.10420720
  0.01  7          0.5               0.9169833  0.11769151
  0.01  7          0.8               0.9119753  0.10873268
  0.05  1          0.5               0.7640699  0.08281792
  0.05  1          0.8               0.7700580  0.09201503
  0.05  2          0.5               0.8709909  0.09034807
  0.05  2          0.8               0.8739990  0.10440898
  0.05  3          0.5               0.9039792  0.12166348
  0.05  3          0.8               0.9089832  0.11850402
  0.05  4          0.5               0.9149793  0.11602447
  0.05  4          0.8               0.9119713  0.11207786
  0.05  5          0.5               0.9139633  0.11853793
  0.05  5          0.8               0.9159754  0.11968085
  0.05  6          0.5               0.9219794  0.11744643
  0.05  6          0.8               0.9199794  0.12803204
  0.05  7          0.5               0.9179873  0.08701058
  0.05  7          0.8               0.9179793  0.10702619

Tuning parameter 'nrounds' was held constant at a value of 500
Tuning parameter 'gamma' was held constant
 at a value of 0
Tuning parameter 'min_child_weight' was held constant at a value of 1
Tuning
 parameter 'subsample' was held constant at a value of 0.6
Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final values used for the model were nrounds = 500, max_depth = 6, eta = 0.05, gamma =
 0, colsample_bytree = 0.5, min_child_weight = 1 and subsample = 0.6.
```

You can also use the non formula interface in which you specify the `x` and `y` separately:

```
caravan.boost <- train(x = data.Caravan.train[,-ncol(data.Caravan.train)],
                       y =  data.Caravan.train$Purchase, 
                       method = "xgbTree", 
                       metric = "Accuracy",
                       trControl = control, 
                       tuneGrid = grid)
```

do note that these two ways of specification do not always produce the same result when there are factor variables in `x` since the formula interface calls `model.matrix` for most algorithms.

To get the data:

```
library(ISLR)
data(Caravan)
```