# breast cancer Wisconsin data analysis

Tags: r

When I run

```
fit.glm <- train(Class~., data=BC, method="glm", metric=metric, trControl=control, na.action=na.omit)
```

I get the following error in my RStudio

> Error: Metric Accuracy not applicable for regression models

Why does it say so?

Comment: Can you specify more code please? Also, did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53343462/error-with-caret-package-classification-v-regression) out?

Answer (score 1):

Do this before fitting your model. Accuracy metric requires factors not numeric data which I suspect you're feeding it:

```
Dataset<-Dataset%>% 
  mutate(Class=as.factor(Class))
```

In the future please provide sample data using `dput(df)`